# Haskell when the user input something.. sum up with the number in the txt file

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

Let's say that the user input = 6000 and the number inside input.txt is = 5000. The sum up will be 11000. The number that will be displayed on the screen and the value stored in the file will be overwritten to 11000. Please help me, Thanks

```
import System.IO

menu :: IO ()
menu = do

handle <- openFile "input.txt" ReadMode  
          contents <- hGetContents handle 
      putStr contents
      hClose handle
      contents <- readFile "input.txt"
      print . sum . read $ contents
      putStr("\nThe amount of money that you want to deposit : ")
      y<-getLine
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Whats wrong with yor code :

Lots of problems with your code.

- Why are you reading two times.
- Why there is a getLine at the end.
- The types of most of the functions you have used do not match.
- Does the input file contains only one line or many lines.

It is better to see types of functions you are using and then compose them.

A probable correction of your code from what I can infer you want would be

```
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
    y<-getLine
    content <- readFile "input.txt"
    let out = sum $ map read $ y:(words content)
    putStrLn $ "\nThe amount of money that you want to deposit : " ++ show out
    writeFile "input.txt" $ show out
```

### Direct answer :

It is better to use `withFile` as you want to read and then write. `readFile` reads the file lazily so there is no guarantee when the file handle will be closed. In the above case if you write the `writeFile` line before printing the output it might give a runtime error complaining about open handles. So `withFile` is a safer option and you will be opening file only once as compared to twice in the above case.

I have considered that you just want to add the number in the first line of the input file with the number you input.

```
import System.IO

main = do
    input <- getLine
    out <- sumFile (read input) "input.txt"
    putStr $ "\nThe amount of money that you want to deposit : " ++ show out

sumFile :: Int -> FilePath -> IO Int
sumFile input fp = withFile fp ReadWriteMode add
    where
        add handle = do
            number <- hGetLine handle
            hSeek handle AbsoluteSeek 0
            let sum = input + read number
            hPutStrLn handle (show sum)
            return sum
```

Comment: sumFile input fp = withFile fp ReadWriteMode add. I got some error about this line of code. it returns "file:.\Haskell Assignment.txt:35 - Syntax error in input (unexpected `=')"

Comment: The reason why i am reading twice is because i want to show the number in the file first and then sum up the number of the input. Finally, overwrite the number in the file and display

Comment: @user1767145 Check indentation.

Comment: Why not just show the number you summed up instead of reading it again from the file.

Comment: @user1767145 you don't need to read it twice to use it twice. In the `sumFile` function above you could add the lines `let thenumber = read number` and `putStrLn $ "The current amount: "++ show thenumber` after the `hGetLine` or `hSeek`. You could then replace `read number` with just `thenumber`.